# Symfony, How to generate Asset URL in a Twig Extension class?

Tags: symfony, twig

I have one class which extends `\Twig_Extension` like below :

```
class MYTwigExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{

    protected $doctrine;

    protected $router;


    public function __construct(RegistryInterface $doctrine , $router)
    {
        $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
        $this->router = $router;

    }

    public function auth_links($user , $request)
    {
       // Some other codes here ...

       // HOW TO GENERATE $iconlink which is like '/path/to/an/image'

       $html .= "<img src=\"$iconlink\" alt=\"\" />  ";  

       echo $html;
    }

}
```

My question is How to generate Asset links in a Twig Extension ? I would like a replacement for ASSET helper in my class. Bassically I have no idea what I have to inject or use here ! Thanks in advance.

```
 <img src="{{ asset('img/icons/modules/timesheet.png') }}" alt="" />
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the **templating.helper.assets** service directly.

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
{
    $this->container = $container;
}
```

and use it like so:

```
$this->container->get('templating.helper.assets')->getUrl($iconlink);
```

Injecting just the **templating.helper.assets** directly does not work in this case because the twig extension cannot be in the request scope. See the documentation here: https://symfony.com/doc/2.3/cookbook/service_container/scopes.html#using-a-service-from-a-narrower-scope

Comment: What should I inject in config.yml ? "@what" ?

Comment: The service id is "templating.helper.assets". So @templating.helper.assets should do it

Comment: It will complain about the scope if you try to inject  templating.helper.assets

Comment: ah, I see, you will have to add `scope: request` to your service definition. Alternatively, you can inject the container itself and then calling $this->container->get('templating.helper.assets') should also work.

Comment: Yes, I did inject the container "@service_container" and I used $this->container->get('templating.helper.assets') . Thanks.

Comment: add scope: request to your service definition, and Symfony 2.1 will bark a huge error message in your face saying Scope Widening Injection detected: The definition "twig" references the service "bb.twig.extension" which belongs to a narrower scope. Generally, it is safer to either move "twig" to scope "request" or alternatively rely on the provider pattern by injecting the container itself, and requesting the service "bb.twig.extension" each time it is needed. In rare, special cases however that might not be necessary, then you can set the reference to strict=false to get rid of this error.

Comment: Is there a reference/source for that service?

Comment: @MDrollette when injecting the container and using get('templating.helper.assets') I still get *You cannot create a service ("templating.helper.assets") of an inactive scope ("request")* when running assetic:dump

Comment: The templating.helper.assets service was replaced in Symfony 3.0.* by assets.packages https://github.com/Gregwar/ImageBundle/issues/92

Comment: Scopes were deprecated and no-one (ideally..) should be using 2.8 now https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-8-deprecating-scopes-and-introducing-shared-services

Answer (score 7):

I didn't want to deal with the Dependency Injection Container. This is what I did:

```
use Twig_Environment as Environment;

class MyTwigExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    protected $twig;
    protected $assetFunction;

    public function initRuntime(Environment $twig)
    {
        $this->twig = $twig;
    }

    protected function asset($asset)
    {
        if (empty($this->assetFunction)) {
             $this->assetFunction = $this->twig->getFunction('asset')->getCallable();
        }
        return call_user_func($this->assetFunction, $asset);
    }
```

I've looked at `Twig_Extension` class code, and found this `initRuntime` method there, to be overriden in our custom Extension class. It receives the `Twig_Environment` as an argument! This object has a `getFunction` method, which returns a `Twig_Function` instance. We only need to pass the function name (`asset`, in our case).

The `Twig_Function` object has a `getCallable` method, so we finally can have a callable `asset` function.

I've gone a bit further creating an `asset` method for my own extension class. Anywhere else on it, I can simply call `$this->asset()` and obtain the same result as `{{ asset() }}` in the templates.

**EDIT**: The `getFunction` call at `initRuntime` throws a scope exception when clearing the cache. So I moved it to the custom `asset` method. It works fine.

Comment: Thank you for this. I much prefer this method over injecting the container

Comment: This will trigger a deprecation warning nowadays which can be fixed by implementing the `Twig_Extension_InitRuntimeInterface` or reworking the code with injection of the `Twig_Environment`:

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#environment-aware-filters

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple and clean way for Symfony 2.8:

services.yml:

```
app.twig_extension:
    class: Path\To\AcmeExtension
    arguments:
        assets: "@templating.helper.assets"
```

In the TWIG extension:

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\Helper\AssetsHelper;

class AcmeExtension
{
    protected $assets;

    public function __construct(AssetsHelper $assets)
    {
        $this->assets = $assets;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it in any function of the extension like this:

```
$this->assets->getUrl('myurl');
```

Answer (score 1):

In **Symfony 5.3** that worked for me:
(just do what the assets extension does and inject Packages)

```php
use Symfony\Component\Asset\Packages;
use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\Extension\ExtensionInterface;

class AppExtension extends AbstractExtension implements ExtensionInterface
{
    public function __construct(Packages $packages)
    {
        $this->packages = $packages;
    }

    // ... your other methods

    private function asset($path, $packageName = null)
    {
        return $this->packages->getUrl($path, $packageName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Symfony 2.8** that works for me:

```
# services.yml
services:
    app.twig_extension:
        class: AppBundle\Twig\AppTwigExtension
        public: false
        arguments:
            - @templating.helper.assets
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

AppTwigExtension class:

```
namespace AppBundle\Twig;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\Helper\AssetsHelper;

/**
 * Class AppTwigExtension
 * @package AppBundle\Twig
 */
class AppTwigExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    const IMG_PATH = 'bundles/app/images/';

    private $assetsHelper;

    public function __construct(AssetsHelper $assetsHelper)
    {
        $this->assetsHelper = $assetsHelper;
    }

    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('img', array($this, 'imagePathFilter'))
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get image path relatively to host
     * Usage in Twig template: {{ 'my_image.png'|img }} - equal to
     * {{ asset('bundles/app/images/my_image.png') }} in Twig template:
     *
     * @param string $imageName (e.g. my_image.png)
     * @return string
     */
    public function imagePathFilter($imageName)
    {
        return $this->assetsHelper->getUrl(self::IMG_PATH . $imageName);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'app_twig_extension';
    }
}
```